# Warning: "rule useless in parser due to conflicts" in Bison

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lexical-analysis, gnuwin32

I am trying to make a C lexical analyzer and I have some warnings:

```
rule useless in parser due to conflicts: sentenceList: sentenceList sentence
rule useless in parser due to conflicts: sentSelection: IF '(' expression ')' sentence
rule useless in parser due to conflicts: sentSelection: IF '(' expression ')' sentence ELSE sentence
rule useless in parser due to conflicts: sentSelection: SWITCH '(' expression ')' sentence
rule useless in parser due to conflicts: sentIteration: WHILE '(' expression ')' sentence
rule useless in parser due to conflicts: sentIteration: FOR '(' expression ';' expression ';' expression ')' sentence
```

This is the part of the code where the warnings come from:

```
input:    /* nothing */
        | input line
;

line:     '\n'
        | sentence '\n' 
;
sentence :       sentComposed
                |sentSelection
                |sentExpression
                |sentIteration
;

sentComposed:     statementsList
                 |sentenceList
;

statementsList:      statement
                   | statementsList statement
;

sentenceList:    sentence
                |sentenceList sentence
;

sentExpression: expression ';'
              |';'
;

sentSelection: IF '(' expression ')' sentence
              |IF '(' expression ')' sentence ELSE sentence
              |SWITCH '(' expression ')' sentence
;

sentIteration: WHILE '(' expression ')' sentence
              |DO sentence WHILE '(' expression ')' ';' 
              |FOR '(' expression ';' expression ';' expression ')' sentence
;

statement: DATATYPE varList                
;

varList:     aVar
            |varList ',' aVar
;

aVar:     variable inicial                           
;

variable: IDENTIFIER                                 
;

initial: '=' NUM                                         
;
```

I have just added some more information 
Every word in uppercase letters are tokens.
If you need any aditional information please tell me

Comment: Not enough information to answer in detail, but it seems the problem is with your non-terminal `sentence`, which you've chosen to not share. Please read about the importance of providing a [mre].

Comment: I'm sorry, I've already edited it

Comment: Still not enough, although I guess we're getting closer. Your excerpt doesn't show any production which uses `sentenceList`, which is necessary to see the context in which a conflict could arise. I'm also puzzled by the fact that the warning includes the production `sentSelection: WHILE '(' expression ')' sentence` but your grammar doesn't; the grammar has `sentIteration: WHILE '(' expression ')' sentence`. That suggests that the warning comes from a different version of your grammar than the one you've included in your question.

Comment: Again, I refer to the help page asking for a [mre]; note that such an example is "Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem". Thanks.

Comment: I've read that article and I think now the information provided is enough. I'm sorry for the delay but I originally wrote the grammar in Spanish so I had to translate it. Tell me if  you need to see the %union and the tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a considerably simplified (but complete) excerpt of your grammar. I've declared `expression` to be a terminal so as to avoid having to define it:

```
%token expression IF
%%
sentence :       sentComposed
                |sentSelection
                |sentExpression
sentComposed:    sentenceList
sentenceList:    sentence
                |sentenceList sentence
sentExpression:  expression ';'
                |';'
sentSelection:   IF '(' expression ')' sentence
```

When I run that through bison, it reports:

```
ez.y: warning: 4 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
ez.y: warning: 8 reduce/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-rr]
```

Those conflicts are the actual problem, as indicated by the following warnings ("due to conflicts"):

```
ez.y:8.18-38: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts [-Wother]
                 |sentenceList sentence
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ez.y:11.18-47: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts [-Wother]
 sentSelection:   IF '(' expression ')' sentence
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When bison finds a conflict in a grammar, it resolves it according to a simple procedure:

- shift-reduce conflicts are resolved in favour of the shift
- reduce-reduce conflicts are resolved in favour of the production which occurs earlier in the grammar.

Once it does that, it might turn out that some production can no longer ever be used, because it was eliminated from every context in which it might have been reduced. That's a clear sign that the grammar is problematic. [Note 1]

The basic problem here is that `sentComposed` means that statements can just be strung together to make a longer statement. So what happens if you write:

```
IF (e) statement1 statement2
```

It could be that `statement1 statement2` is intended to be reduced into a single `sentComposed` which is the target of the `IF`, so the two statements execute only if `e` is true. Or it could be that the `sentComposed` consists of the `IF` statement with target `statement1`, followed by `statement2`. In C terms, the difference is between:

```
if (e) { statement1; statement2; }
```

and

```
{ if (e) { statement1; } statement2; }
```

So that's a real ambiguity, and you probably need to rethink the absence of braces in order to fix it.

But that's not the only problem; you also have a bunch of reduce-reduce conflicts. Those come about in a much simpler way, because part of the above grammar is the following loop:

```
sentence:     sentComposed
sentComposed: sentenceList
sentenceList: sentence
```

That loop means that your grammar allows a single `sentence` to be wrapped in an arbitrary number of unit reductions. You certainly did not intend that; I'm certain that your intent was that `sentComposed` only be used if actually necessary. But bison doesn't know your intent; it only knows what you say.

Again, you will probably solve this problem when you figure out how you actually want to identify the boundaries of a `sentComposed`.

#### Notes:

1. In some cases, conflicts are not actually a problem. For example, there is a shift-reduce conflict between these two productions; the so-called "dangling-else" ambiguity:

   ```
   sentSelection: IF '(' expression ')' sentence
                 |IF '(' expression ')' sentence ELSE sentence
   ```

   In a nested `IF` statement:

   ```
   IF (e) IF (f) s1 ELSE s2
   ```

   it's not clear whether the `ELSE` should apply to the inner or outer `IF`. If it applies to the inner `IF`, it must be shifted to allow the second production for `sentSelection`. If it applies to the outer `IF`, a reduction must first be performed to complete the inner (else-less) `IF` before shifting `ELSE` into the outer `IF`. Bison's default action ("prefer shift") does exactly the right thing in this case, which is to shift the `ELSE` immediately. (Indeed, that's why the default was chosen to be "prefer shift").